# getFirst in Symfony doesn't return anything

Tags: php, symfony1

I have a question about symfony. I'm working on a website and everything was going great, when suddently, without even touching, it all stoped. I narrow it down to a problem in my "getClient" function. Here's the code: (im using doAuthPlugin if that matters)

in: app/client/lib/myUser.class.php:

```
public function getClient()
{

    $uTemp = $this->getAccount()->getClients()->getFirst();

    $userId = $uTemp['_data']['userid'];

    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from('Client c')
        ->where('c.id  = ?', $userId);

    $result = $q->fetchArray();

    if(sizeof($result) > 0){

        return $this->getAccount()->getClients()->getFirst();
    }else{

        return false;
    }
}
```

On the first line, $uTemp == false. Although there is something in $this->getAccount()->getClients().

If someone could shed some light on this, I really suck with Symfony! :p

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's get Account:

```
public function getAccount()
{
   if (!$this->user && $id = $this->getAttribute('user_id', null, 'doUser'))
   {
      $this->user = Doctrine::getTable('User')->find($id);

      if (!$this->user)
      {
        // the user does not exist anymore in the database
        $this->signOut();

        throw new sfException('The user does not exist anymore in the database.');
      }
    }

   return $this->user;
 }
```

I cannot find getClients, it's automatically generated by symfony (and since I don't know symfony that much...)

EDIT 2:

if I do a var_dump on $this->getAccount->getClients(), it's empty:

```
object(Client)#123 (18) {
  ["_node":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_id":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_data":protected]=>
  array(14) {
    ["id"]=>
    object(Doctrine_Null)#12 (0) {
    }
    ["userid"]=>
    object(Doctrine_Null)#12 (0) {
    }
    ["name"]=>
    object(Doctrine_Null)#12 (0) {
    }
    ["firstname"]=>
    object(Doctrine_Null)#12 (0) {
    }
    ["phone"]=>
    object(Doctrine_Null)#12 (0) {
    }
    ["cellphone"]=>
    object(Doctrine_Null)#12 (0) {
    }
    ["postalcode"]=>
    object(Doctrine_Null)#12 (0) {
    }
    ["experience"]=>
    object(Doctrine_Null)#12 (0) {
    }
    ["connexe"]=>
    object(Doctrine_Null)#12 (0) {
    }
    ["formation"]=>
    object(Doctrine_Null)#12 (0) {
    }
    ["cv_file"]=>
    object(Doctrine_Null)#12 (0) {
    }
    ["is_active"]=>
    int(0)
    ["created_at"]=>
    object(Doctrine_Null)#12 (0) {
    }
    ["updated_at"]=>
    object(Doctrine_Null)#12 (0) {
    }
}
```

But $this->getAccount does return something

Comment: Can you show the methods `getAccount()` and `getClients()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe getFirst() doesnt work with fetchArray(). 
change this for:

```
$result = $q->execute();
```

maybe this also working with fetchArray():

```
if(sizeof($result) > 0){

    return $result['Account']['Clients'][0];
}else{

    return false;
}
```

Sorry, my mistake.

if you use $this->getAccount()->getClients() then also is NULL ? maybe $this->getAccount()->getClients() return NULL ?

UPDATE:

$uTemp = $this->getAccountId(); // (i dont know your schema.yml)

in ClientsTable.class.php:

```
public function getClientsAccount($id) 
    {        
        $q = $this->createQuery('u')
            ->where('u.client_id = ?', $id);

        return $q->execute();        
    }
```

and next in myUser.class.php you can use:

```
$clients = $this->getAccountId(); // (i dont know your schema.yml)

$uTemp = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Clients')->getClientsAccount($uTemp);
```

maybe this also working:

```
$uTemp = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Clients')->getClientsAccount($uTemp)->getFirst();
```

good luck!

Comment: the OP is not using $result in the return line so the fetchArray() is not important (-1 removed)

Comment: Thanls for the quick answers: $this->getAccount()->getClients() doesn't return NULL

Comment: try parse this to array, and get first record

Comment: I've updated part of what getClients contains. I can't parse the first element of array since it's empty

Comment: try first get id of Account and next write custom function in model - getting Clients for Account.

Comment: Could you be more explicite please? I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Unfortunatly, i'm (extremely) new with symfony...

Comment: Thank you so much! (although in : $uTemp = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Clients')->getClientsAccount($uTemp);
 it should be $clients instead of $uTemp ;) )